# Burnside Lemma's on a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ cube.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

> Assume you have eight $1 \times 1 \times 1$ cubes, each of different colours in which you can make a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ cube. How many unique combinations are possible without rotation symmetry, reflective symmetry, etc. This means eight colours, each cube of a different colour.

Here we need to apply Burnside Lemma's theorem. Can anyone please kindly give me an explanation on how this works? I do not have an answer as I always get confused, but definitely know this.

There are the following rotations:

- one identity element
- six 90-degree face rotations,
- three 180-degree face rotations,
- eight 120-degree vertex rotations,
- six 180-degree edge rotations,

I am trying to learn this myself, and I cannot.

Comment: Because the eight small cubes all have distinct colors it looks like no non-identity symmetry of the cube will fix any arrangement, doesn't it?

Comment: But where did that $36$ come from? It seems to me that $X$ should be the set of $8!=40320$ possible ways of placing the smaller cubes. And when you include reflections and combinations of reflections and rotations the size of the full symmetry group of the cube is doubled, i..e. $48$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I made a mistake, so is it just 8!/48. Can you explain where did 48 come from?